# Stop selling if max qty product is reached (MySQL database)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very populair product and only 100 are available, but 1000+ people want it at the same time. So they all select the product at almost the same time and press the button "Order!". But, only 100 products can be sold to the people ordering, what is the best way to handle the load?

I am working with PHP & MySQL.

The option i'm using right now (very simple example, don't mind sql injection etc.. The real SQL is secure):

```
<?php

$product_id_selected = $_GET['product_id']; // orderd product
$qty_selected = $_GET['qty']; // qty of orderd product

$max_qty = "Select `max_qty` FROM `Product` WHERE `id_id` = 1";
$bought = "Select count(*) as `count` FROM `Orders` WHERE `product_id` = ".$product_id_selected;

$left = $max_qty - $bought;


if($left >= $qty_selected){
 // Full order can be placed

}elseif($left > 0){
   $qty_selected = $left; // only the available left are selected
}else{
   $qty_selected = 0;
}
if($qty_selected>0){
   for($i=0;$i<$qty_selected;$i++){
      $insert = "INSERT INTO `Orderds` (`product_id`) VALUES ($product_id_selected)";
   }
}

?>
```

MySQL example database (real database is more complex):

**Product**:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| id | product_name       | max_qty |
+----+--------------------+---------+
| 1  | Very Populair item | 100     |
+-----------------------------------+
```

**Orders**:

```
+-------------------------+
| id | product_id | payed |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          | 1     |
+----+------------+-------+
```

So my question, is there a better and safer way to do this? Maybe work with a trigger in MySQL so when a order is made it will add 1 to a counter in the database?

I hope someone has a better solution, because mine isn't working with to much load.

Comment: Why don't ALTER the quantity column and decrease it?

Comment: I would use another table to lock the product for someone.  Similar to how ticketing system works.  When they add to cart you pull one from available inventory and put it into holding table with an expiration.  Either the user buys it and then goes into order table and stays out of inventory or it expires and gets added back into inventory.  You would then have an event or process running to check for expired products to put back.

Comment: minus orders from the count in the select query. your very libel to be hacked with that code BTW

Comment: I would suggest you to use lock tables and sessions in order to lock a table for an x amount of time let's say 2 minutes, so every time the user adds a product in the cart, you simply add an entry to another lock table, every row of the lock table is attached to a unique order. If the order is done then then before closing the order you simply select all the products of the lock table having the unique id and for each of them substract from the main table the amount bought, else the order has been cancelled just delete the rows in the lock table